# where does ansroid.os.SystemProperties store its key/values?

Tags: android

As we all know, we can using the `android.os.SystemProperties.set(String, String)` and `android.os.SystemProperties.get(String, String)` for setting and getting values, my question is where does these `<key value>` pairs store? Sqlite database or a pure text file? If so, which directory can we find them?

Comment: For those reading the question and wondering, there is no `android.os.SystemProperties` class in the Android SDK. This is an internal part of Android.

Comment: I don't think we can get access to that directory programmatically...

Comment: currently i store my private property in Settings.Secure table, but unfortunately, if i encrypt the phone(ics supports this feature), when the phone is booting up, the table(/data/date/com.android.providers) doesn't exist yet, so the property always equals 0(default value), so i want to store it in SystemProperties, anyone knows if this manner will be ok?

Answer (score 6):

For `persist.xxx` properties, it's stored under /data/property with the property name as the filename. For other non-persist properties, it's stored in shared memory.

Comment: but note that, this place is written by another process when android init. (I'm finding out where). so those modified files will reset when reboot device.

Answer (score 1):

Because Android is based on Linux, there is no way to read these settings from a file or database or something like that, *because it does not exists.*

While booting your device, the kernel stores the list of environment variables into the memory.

Each process, which is started by an application or by you, is cloning the variables from his parent process and can define his own variables.

In Linux you can access a virtual file stored in `/proc/'pid'/environ` but 1. this is realy not recommended and 2. it doesn't not look like that there is such a file in android filesystem.

If I am wrong with my assumption, please let me know :)

Comment: I think this answer does not anwer this question, it refers to environment variables, not android properties set with 'setprop' or read by 'getprop'.